# Titanium Continue Recording after playing the recorded file

Tags: iphone, titanium, record

I have following code.

```
recording.start();
file = recording.stop();

sound = Titanium.Media.createSound({sound:file});

sound.play();
```

After the completion of Play back can I continue Recording? How we can implement this?

Is there any way to play the recording file when recording is Paused?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `complete` event listener that starts recording again?

```
sound.addEventListener('complete', function(e) {
    // start new recording code here
});
```

Comment: @Brain I dont want to start new recording actually. I want to continue recording. How do i do this?

Comment: just use the `pause` and `resume` methods. http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Media.AudioRecorder.resume-method.html so instead of `recording.stop()` you want `recording.pause()`